# Insert into multiple selects from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `users` (`id`, `email`), `permissions` (`id`, `description`) and `users_permissions` (`user_id`, `permission_id`, `created`) with many to many relation.

I need to select user with some email and assign to him all permissions from table `permissions`, which he does not have.

Now I am trying to assign at least all permissions, but I am getting error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

My query:

```
insert into `users_permissions` (`user_id`, `permission_id`, `created`)
    select 
        (select `id` from `users` where `email` = 'user-abuser@gmail.com') as `user_id`,
        (select `id` from `permissions`) as `permission_id`,
        now() as `created`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a subquery (inside `SELECT`) returns more than one row, MySQL does not like it.

Another way to achieve your requirement is using `CROSS JOIN` between Derived Tables (subquery in the `FROM` clause):

```
INSERT INTO `users_permissions` (`user_id`, `permission_id`, `created`)
    SELECT 
      u.id, 
      p.id, 
      NOW() 
    FROM 
      users AS u 
    CROSS JOIN permissions AS p 
    WHERE u.email = 'user-abuser@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as I expected :) 
Can it somehow insert only permissions which user does not have in table `users_permissions` ?

Comment: @domanskyi Yes. In that case you will need a left join with user_permissions table and consider only those cases where the join results in null